# Batch array keeps previous value

Tags: batch-file, command-line

Running this script

```
@echo off

set "MemuConsole=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microvirt\MEmu\memuc.exe"
set Arr[0]=FIRST ELEM
set Arr[1]=SECOND ELEM
set "x=0"

:SymLoop
if defined Arr[%x%] (
    call set VAL=%%Arr[%x%]%%
    call echo %VAL%

    set /a "x+=1"
    goto :SymLoop
)
```

I can see expected output as:

```
FIRST ELEM
SECOND ELEM
```

Why different script:

```
@echo off

set "MemuConsole=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microvirt\MEmu\memuc.exe"
set Arr[0]=FIRST ELEM
set "x=0"

:SymLoop
if defined Arr[%x%] (
    call set VAL=%%Arr[%x%]%%
    call echo %VAL%

    set /a "x+=1"
    goto :SymLoop
)
```

Is giving me the same output? I removed `set Arr[1]=SECOND ELEM` but it is still printed.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard I added `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion` after `@echo off` but it doesnt solved my problem

Comment: `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` only *enables* delayed expansion. You also have to *use*  it (with `!var!` instead of `%var%`, as shown by @Gerhard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this is what you wanted:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "MemuConsole=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microvirt\MEmu\memuc.exe"

set Arr[0]=FIRST ELEM
set Arr[1]=SECOND ELEM
set x=0

:SymLoop
if defined Arr[%x%] (
    call set VAL=%%Arr[!x!]%%
    call echo !VAL!

    set /a x+=1
    goto :SymLoop
)
```

You can remove `Arr[1]` from this example to test result.

Notice how `Delayedexcpansion` is used replacing `%` with `!`